# Можно ли процитировать диалог в подбор: текст автора – двоеточие – кавычки, открывающие цитату – тире без абзаца...?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата, диалог, абзац

Если надо вставить в текст цитату, содержащую диалог, возможно ли это сделать без абзацев, обычных для диалога? Придётся ли вводить в цитату какие-то дополнительные знаки (кавычки, например), чтобы диалог процитировать в подбор?

**Вот оригинал (только с репликами):**

> – Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения.
>   –
>   Это упадочничество.
>   – Это жизнь. Один завоевывает медаль, другой же
>   пишет на ней его имя.
>   – Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта
>   работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем.

**Вот текст (без правок), в который должна быть вставлена цитата:**

А потом выходит, что специалисты, как в "Покровских воротах", говорили о разных вещах и на разных языках: **"Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения. – Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем".**

**Варианты?**

- А потом выходит, что специалисты, как в "Покровских воротах", говорили о разных вещах и на разных языках: *"– Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения... – Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем".*
- А потом выходит, что специалисты, как в "Покровских воротах", говорили о разных вещах и на разных языках: *"+Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения...+ – +Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем+".* [Здесь + обозначает другой вид кавычек.] Но вопрос: употребление иного способа передачи прямой речи (с помощью схемы: "реплека1"... – "реплика2".) не является ли искажением цитаты, ведь в оригинале диалог передавался по-другому? Да и в целом, прямая речь с абзацами, если цитировать, как в оригинале, в данном тексте неуместна. Но это тоже, в какой-то мере, искажение цитаты: в оригинале есть абзацы.

  ### Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну запросто же! Между репликами персонажей, закавыченными, ставится тире.

*А потом выходит, что специалисты, как в "Покровских воротах", говорили о разных вещах и на разных языках: "Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения". – "Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем".*

После "языках" и точка хороша будет.

А ещё можно, сохраняя значение, смысловую нагрузку двоеточия, примеры говорения "на разных языках" заключить в скобки:

*А потом выходит, что специалисты, как в "Покровских воротах", говорили о разных вещах и на разных языках ("Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения. – Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем").*

Последний вариант, со скобками, всех краше будет.

И никаких разного рисунка кавычек!

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! У Вас в первом варианте предложения нет кавычки после тире: ...работа, требующая самоотречения". – Не знаю, как самоотречения... Она выполняется спицштихелем". Она должна быть? А кавычки другого рисунка не нужны, потому что здесь одни кавычки несут двойную функцию: и обозначают начало/ конец цитаты, и указывают на начало/конец реплики одновременно?

Comment: Простите, ещё: после первой кавычки перед Гравировать не нужно тире?

Comment: Извините, кавычку - обязательную - перед началом ответной реплики просто пропустила, нужна она (исправила в тексте). А тире внутри реплик - ни за что! И кавычки не несут дополнительной функции. Это правило: диалог в подбор - закавычена каждая реплика, между ними тире.

Comment: Поняла. Тогда второй вариант в скобках: ("Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения. – Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем") — тоже надо оформить так: ("Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения". – "Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем")? Так?

Comment: Да, так! ***("Гравировать имена победителей — работа, требующая самоотречения". – "Не знаю, как самоотречения, а тонкости эта работа не требует. Она выполняется спицштихелем".)***

Answer (score 2):

Нарушений правил цитирования получается многовато. Есть такой путь решения (когда из диалога выбрано необходимое) в двух вариантах:

> ... специалисты, как в «Покровских воротах», говорили о разных вещах и
>   на разных языках,  один: «Гравировать имена победителей — работа,
>   требующая самоотречения», другой же: «Не знаю, как самоотречения, а
>   тонкости эта работа не требует».
>
> ... специалисты, как в «Покровских воротах», говорили о разных вещах и
>   на разных языках:  один — «Гравировать имена победителей — работа,
>   требующая самоотречения», другой же — «Не знаю, как самоотречения, а
>   тонкости эта работа не требует».